# How to retrieve scraped data using asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am a noob who is trying to scrape a list of urls and search for a word using asynchronous programming in python.
My code is as follows:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

def parse(wd, html, url):
    add_soup = bsoup(html,'html.parser')
    res = []
    for para in (add_soup.find_all("p")):
        para_txt = para.text
        for sent_txt in para_txt.split("."):
            if wd in sent_txt:
                res.append([sent_txt, url])
    return res

async def scrape_urls(wd, urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(
            *(fetch_and_parse(wd, session, url) for url in urls)
        )

async def fetch_and_parse(wd, session, url):
    html = await fetch(wd, session, url)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    paras = await loop.run_in_executor(None, parse, html)
    return paras
```

I wrote the above code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540835/where-to-put-beautifulsoup-code-in-asyncio-web-scraping-application). But I am unclear as how to proceed to retrieve the resultant list

I am trying to get the results using this `co = scrape_urls("agriculture", urls)`. As expected I get a coroutine object. How do I parse the coroutine object?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? What should the expected result look like?

Comment: @QHarr, I dont know how to parse the resultant coroutine object. I am expecting a list of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what issue you're facing. Once you use `gather` to get the Future instance, use an event loop to execute it and get results.

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
group = scrape_urls("agriculture", urls)
results = loop.run_until_complete(group)
loop.close()
print(results)
```