# How to make webscraping with BeautifulSoup Faster

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this piece of code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

asins = []
articlesdownload = []

with open('asins.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        asins.append(row[0])

for asin in asins:
    url = f'https://scrape.com/{asin}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='lxml')

    articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='single-view')

    for item in articles:
        title = item.find('h1', class_="entry-title").text
        title_url = item.h1.a['href']
        author = item.find('div', class_='entry-author').a.text
        author_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-author').a['href']
        published_date = item.find('div', class_='entry-date').text.replace('\n','')
        category = item.find('div', class_='entry-categories').text.replace('\n','')
        category_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-categories')
        category_all_url = category_url.find_all('a', href=True)
        try:
            image_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-content cf').p.img['src']
        except:
            image_url = item.find('div', class_='wp-caption').img['src']
        dgdrive_link = item.find('div', class_='entry-content').h2.a['href']
        drive_link = item.select('h2:nth-of-type(2) > strong > a')
        tags = item.find('div', class_='entry-tags').text.replace('Tags: ','')
        tags_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-tags')
        tag = tags_url.find_all('a', href=True)

        article_info = {
        'Title': title,
        'Post URL': title_url,
        'Author': author,
        'Author URL': author_url,
        'Published Date': published_date,
        'Category': category,
        'Category URL': category_all_url,
        'Image URL': image_url,
        'Tags': tags,
        'Tags URL': tags_url,
        'DG Drive Link': dgdrive_link,
        'Google Drive Link': drive_link
        }
        articlesdownload.append(article_info)
    print('Articles Found: ', len(articlesdownload))


    df = pd.DataFrame(articlesdownload)

    df.to_csv('articlesdownload.csv')
```

`asins.csv` has the list of the suffix of URLs, It scrapes the data from the articles one by one and appends all scraped data to `articlesdownload.csv`.

The code is supposed to scrape data from 12093 articles.

The problem is it's really slow for such a simple task. what is the correct way to implement multiprocessing to speed it up?

I'm a newbie and I don't know much about python and multiprocessing

Comment: Search for asyncio and beautifulsoup. Here's one SO link as an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540835/where-to-put-beautifulsoup-code-in-asyncio-web-scraping-application

Comment: Can someone please modify my code with asyncio? I am not good at creating functions.

Comment: Are you able to provide the actual URL you are scraping and a few of the entries from asins.csv?