# Speed up web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

i want to scrape this page : https://annumed.sante-dz.com/annuaire?page=500 with this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = []
for page in range(1, 4308):   # <-- increase number of pages here
    print("Page", page)
    url = f"https://annumed.sante-dz.com/annuaire?page={page}"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.select(".info:has(header)"):
        name = i.h3.text
        spec = i.select_one("header p").text
        cats = [s.text for s in i.select(".speciliate")]
        addr = i.select_one(".address__wrapper").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        data.append((name, spec, ",".join(cats), addr))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Spec", "Categories", "Address"])

# Define the file path for the Excel file
excel_file_path = r"C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\scraping_sante\sectr_med.xlsx"

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)
print("Data saved to Excel:", excel_file_path)
```

but it take long time to complet all pages because the web site contain 4308 pages so i want methode to minimise time

this code that works well, but it takes a long time because there are many pages: 4308 pages, sometimes the entire day, and it doesn't finish. So, I'm looking for a method to reduce the time.

Comment: You can look into [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786225/22390653)

Answer (score 1):

You can use asyncio and aiohttp to speed up your requests. Others have asked similar questions that contain answers.the link: [Where to put BeautifulSoup code in Asyncio Web Scraping Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540835/where-to-put-beautifulsoup-code-in-asyncio-web-scraping-application) you will find how to use beautiful soup with asnycio web scraping. Here on [How does asyncio actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work) you will find examples. If you still are having issues grasping asnycio I suggest you look over the documentation.

The code down below took me 9.230624390002049 seconds to get data and make it into a dataframe. Note, I saved the information to a dictionary since the values were not saving correctly to the dataframe the way you had it coded:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

async def fetch(session, url):
  async with session.get(url) as response:
    return await response.text()

def parse(html):
  data = []
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
  for i in soup.select(".info:has(header)"):
    dict_item = {}
    dict_item['name'] = i.h3.text
    dict_item['spec'] = i.select_one("header p").text
    dict_item['cats'] = [s.text for s in i.select(".speciliate")]
    dict_item['addr'] = i.select_one(".address__wrapper").get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    data.append(dict_item)
  return data

async def fetch_and_parse(session, url):
  html = await fetch(session, url)
  paras = parse(html)
  return paras

async def scrape_urls(urls):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    return await asyncio.gather(
        *(fetch_and_parse(session, url) for url in urls))

def make_urls():   
  urls  = []
  for page in range(1,10): # change range to your liking
    urls.append(f"https://annumed.sante-dz.com/annuaire?page={page}")
  return urls

res = asyncio.run(scrape_urls(make_urls()))

print(res)
df = pd.DataFrame(res[0])
print((df))
```

Your code took me 61.47077561899641 seconds to get the status codes of 10 urls. I don't think my solution is the most efficient but it's something to get you started until someone else posts something faster! Good luck